# Swift OSX: simultaneous command + non modifier key events

Tags: swift, macos

I've been trying to find this one on stack overflow, but only got a link about simultaneous non modifier keys being pressed which requires some state checking to get the desired result.

I am trying to create commands such as command+1, command+2, ..., command+n or option+I or ctrl+q, each a combination of a modifier key and non modifier key.

I use all the overrides such as keyDown and keyUp and use InterpretKeyEvents to override other keys such as cancelOperation or newLine.

I found an override which takes the state of a modifier key (flagsChanged)

But the above does seem to only register the state of the modifier key which I can pull out with NSEvent's modifier flag checker, but I can't seem to get the simultaneous keypress to call the desired function.

I am trying to use different combinations to access the numerical keys so each modifier+numerical will give me a different configuration of that number.

Comment: Creating Menu items might help. Each menu item can have a keyboard shortcut. Refer https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MenuList/MenuList.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000032i

Comment: Handling key equivalents is explained in the "Handling Key Equivalents" section of https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/EventOverview/HandlingKeyEvents/HandlingKeyEvents.html

Answer (score 0):

So for the sake of completeness, and thanks to suggestions from you guys, here's an approach I took:

1-Dictionary of alphanumerical keys pointing to integers
2-dictionary pointing to functions associated to the integer returns of the alfanumericals
3-The code for the key capture below. it can be improved by associating 2 function pointers to the modifier rawIndex value but this should suffice for anyone who may have an issue or may ask the same question. profiling, I get on average 0.2 - 0.8 ms response time between keypress and called function trail end.

```
    override func keyDown(with event: NSEvent) {
        let modifierFlags = event.modifierFlags
        let key = event.characters!
        if !event.isARepeat{
            if modifierFlags.rawValue == 256{
//No modifiers pressed
                guard let track = Int(key) else{
//not a number key so proceed with the function library containing relevant pointers
                    functionLib[keys[key]!]!(0)
//keys is [String: Int]
                    return
                }
//Proceed with another function as we are using number keys
                command(keys[key]!)
            }else if modifierFlags.contains(NSEventModifierFlags.command){
//Command key is being pressed simultaneously
                guard let track = Int(key) else{
//Go into command and non number key combinations
                    functionLib[commandKeys[key]!]!(0)
                    return
                }
//Command and number key combo function call
                openTrack(track)
            }
    }
    }
```

note: There are void functions in the function library to allow non mapped keys to lead to a return function, so having several, dictionaries: keys only, command+key, option+key, etc.. are useful for getting a full set of commands to be used.
Also, one extra step to avoid if else statements and gain 1-3 asymptotic points is to associate the modifier key rawValue to its own dict. probably something of a monadish structure but it seems fast enough.